# Rails 4 partial locals undefined variable error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I am rendering a bunch of tables with a graph, all the same type of data repeated a number of times so I wanted to use a partial for DRY code purposes.

This is the code I call in the view:

```
  <%= render 'app_usage', locals: {
    metric: "Sessions", 
    new_total: @flurry_total, 
    old_total: @flurry_old_total, 
    growth: flurry_growth,
    chart_data: flurry_chart
    } %>
```

and in `_app_usage.html.erb`

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Metric:</td><td><%= metric %></td></tr>
...
```

However I get an error for the `<tr><td>Metric:</td><td><%= metric %></td></tr>` saying the variable `metric` is undefined. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `partial` syntax to invoke [the `ActionView::PartialRenderer` with `locals`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html):

```
<%= render partial: 'app_usage', locals: {
    metric: "Sessions", 
    new_total: @flurry_total, 
    old_total: @flurry_old_total, 
    growth: flurry_growth,
    chart_data: flurry_chart
    } %>
```

Comment: He he yes... I missed it.

Comment: But without partial syntax how Rails reach to the partial is making me crazy if I follow OP...

Comment: @ArupRakshit You can invoke a partial if you're not looking to pass your own `layout` or `locals` using the regular `render` syntax. See "Rendering the default case" from the link in my answer :)

Comment: Well, I read it. Then I think OP;s code will work without `locals: {}`.. OP needs to pass those key/values as arguments.....